# numpy array multiplication issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have three arrays (that is, of type `numpy.array`):

```
>>> w.shape
(113,)
>>> X.shape
(113,1)
>>> Y.shape
(113,)
```

The numpy help pages suggest that on arrays every multiplication is element-wise. Since all above three vectors are of size 113 in the first dimension, I thought multiplication would in all cases give a 113 length vector, but it doesn't:

```
>>> (w * Y).shape     # expected
(113,)
>>> (w * X).shape     # ?!?!?!?!
(113,113)
```

Where does the 113 on the second axis come from? Doesn't look so element-wise to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when they are equal, or one
>   of them is 1.

**The smaller of two axes is stretched or “copied” to match
the other.**

Numpy's **[broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)** rules are being applied here.

```
w      (1d array):       113
X      (2d array): 113 x   1   
Result (2d array): 113 x 113
```

Comment: Aha, "starts with the ***trailing*** dimension"! Thanks.

Comment: If you want a `(N,1)` result for the multiplication of `x (N,)` with `y (N,1)`, use `x[:,None]*y` to force broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see what's going on is with an example:

```
w = array([5,6])
x = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
z = array([[5,6]])

w*x
# array([[ 5, 12],
#        [15, 24]])

w*z
# array([[25, 36]])
```